# beginner question, using sklearn, saving model and test a single dataframe

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

New to python neural networks and sklearn, i wrote the following neural model. On a train set, it works nicely around 98% accuracy.
Now i have some questions.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
model = GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.99,max_depth=3)
model.fit(X_standardized, y)
predictions = model.predict(X_standardized)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
print(confusion_matrix(y, predictions))
print ()
print(classification_report(y,predictions))
```

Can the state of the neural network be saved and loaded.
ea store the weights gradients.

```
#something like:
Model.save("c:\neural\testnet.xml")
```

How to perform individual tests on a single data frame ea:

```
print ("answer =" ,Model.TestSample(test_data_frame))  # single input
   >>> answer = 0.78     ...estimated accuracy 97%  # or so
```

Comment: use `joblib` to save model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding saving the state of the model: you can save the model using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) package, e.g.:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(model, open('model.sav', 'wb'))
```

Not sure what you mean by 'individual tests on a single data frame', but if you want to test the model on some different (test) data, you can just create something like that:

```
import sklearn
df_predictions = model.predict( *input X data* )
accuracy = sklearn.metrics.r2_score(*target (y data)*, df_predictions)
```